# Orientation change during server side call

Tags: java, android

I have basically handled things `onSaveInstanceState` method, then when activity is recreated i just read the values.
However the problem is, imagine i have a list ,i call a server side function.
the orientation is changed before that list is brought from server side.... whats the solution here?
Do I disable orientation programmatically during server side calls and if so how? Whats the solution?

```
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    try
    {
         EditText passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
         EditText usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
         outState.putString("username", usernameField.getText().toString());
         outState.putString("password", passwordField.getText().toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
}
```

Comment: what is your xml code....add xml part here to see exact issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop activity restart (means during orientation change onCreate will not again called) on Orientation change by adding this to AndroidMenifest.xml file

Start by adding the android:configChanges node to your Activity's manifest node

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

or for Android 3.2 (API level 13) and newer:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: okey thank you for the answer, so i wouldn't need to handle onsaveinstancestate ? it would become redundant

Comment: Ya exactly, if you like then please +1 and accept the answer so it would be helpful to other also, I have given ur question +1 vote :)